# Undefined reference to func from another project in Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I have 2 projects in CodeBlocks:

**TuringMachine**

*MyExp.h*

```
class MyExp
{
public:
    MyExp() = default;
    double myExpFunc(double);
};
```

*MyExp.cpp*

```
#include "MyExp.h"
double MyExp::myExpFunc(double x) //fixed the lack of MyExp::, but still doesn't work
{ 
    return x*x;
}
```

And the second project: **TuringMachineTests**

*main.cpp*

```
#include "../include/MyExp.h"
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE MyTest
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( my_test )
{
        MyExp me;
        int val = me.myExpFunc(5.0);

        BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(val, 24);
}
```

Boost stuff works properly (w/o calling myExpFunc everything works). The paths are also proper (TuringMachineTest's dir is in TuringMachine's dir).

But compiler says:

```
||=== Build: Debug in TuringMachine (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
||=== Build: Debug in TuringMachineTests (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
obj/Debug/main.o||In function `my_test::test_method()':|
.../TuringMachine/TuringMachineTests/main.cpp|8|undefined reference to `MyExp::myExpFunc(double)'|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

It sounds like Tests project cannot find *MyExp.cpp* (note that default ctor was called normally). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the class name, at the implementation of your method:

```
double MyExp::myExpFunc(double x)
//     ^^^^^^^
{
    ...
}
```

Further you have to add file 'MyExp.cpp' to the project. The file has to be compiled and linked. Otherwise you will get an error during linking (undefined reference to `MyExp::myExpFunc').

Comment: sure, you are right, silly mistake :) But after that it still doesn't work, the same output of the compiler

Comment: Do you mean to simpy add file to the project? Including a header file is not sufficient?

Comment: Ok, it works. But it isn't very nice (hard addition). May exist some more elegant solution?

Comment: Ok, thanks. May you add new answer with adding the .cpp file to Test project? It is the solution for this question and I want to mark it as correct (for future readers)

Comment: Is your class in a namespace?

Comment: @zackery.fix what about do you think with namespaces? I don't get it. Do you mean "TuringMachine" project namespace?

Comment: If your class was in a namespace, this is could have been another issue as to why the compiler couldn't find `MyExp::myExpFunc()`.  You would have to put the defintion inside a `namespace MyNamespace { }` scope, or put the namespace name at the front of the symbol being defined: `MyNamespace::MyExp::myExpFunc()`